# Format Date as "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

Tags: javascript, facebook, date, date-format, parse-platform

I need to format a date as `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` as specified by [Parse's REST API for Facebook](https://parse.com/docs/rest#users-login). I was wondering what the most **lightweight** solution to this would be.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Call the [`toISOString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff925953%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) method:

```
var dt = new Date("30 July 2010 15:05 UTC");
document.write(dt.toISOString());

// Output:
//  2010-07-30T15:05:00.000Z
```

Comment: How could you go the other direction?

Comment: @user1789573: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 21):

`toISOString()` will return current UTC time only not the current local time. If you want to get the current local time in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ` format then you should get the current time using following two methods

## Method 1:

```js
console.log(new Date(new Date().toString().split('GMT')[0]+' UTC').toISOString());
```

## Method 2:

```js
console.log(new Date(new Date().getTime() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString());
```

Comment: would be better without `document.write(...)` around it. +1

Answer (score 7):

```
function converToLocalTime(serverDate) {

    var dt = new Date(Date.parse(serverDate));
    var localDate = dt;
    
    var gmt = localDate;
        var min = gmt.getTime() / 1000 / 60; // convert gmt date to minutes
        var localNow = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); // get the timezone
        // offset in minutes
        var localTime = min - localNow; // get the local time

    var dateStr = new Date(localTime * 1000 * 60);
    // dateStr = dateStr.toISOString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"); // this will return as just the server date format i.e., yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
    dateStr = dateStr.toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    return dateStr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add another option, maybe not the most lightweight.

```js
dayjs.extend(dayjs_plugin_customParseFormat)
console.log(dayjs('2018-09-06 17:00:00').format( 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000ZZ'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1.9.7/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1.9.7/plugin/customParseFormat.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js

```
const offsetInMinutes = 2 * 60 ; //Romanian
const todaysDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + offsetInMinutes * 60000).toISOString();
```

Answer (score -8):

You can use  `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` class

`DatatypeConverter.printDateTime`
&
`DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime`

Comment: This is a `Javascript` question, not `Java`