# How can I modify T and Z date format to normal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to show the date current date and time according to country but the date showing me as "2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z" and I don't know how to do with javascript.

This is Js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : "/getMessages/{{room}}/",
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                $("#display").empty();
                for (var key in response.messages)
                {
                    var temp="<div class='main-content darker'><b>"+response.messages[key].user+"</b><p>"+response.messages[key].value+"</p><span class='time-right'>"+response.messages[key].date+"</span></div>";
                    $("#display").append(temp);
                }
            },
            error: function(response){
                alert('An error occured')
            }
        });
    },1000);
    });
```

Please, can anyone help me to get out of this, any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: maybe this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945003/format-date-as-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz

Comment: hint: `new Date("2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z").toString()`

Comment: hey i think this answer will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945003/format-date-as-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz

Comment: @AarushKumar - read the questions again ... you'll see they are opposite of each other :p